# how could - I count the number of parameters in an URL using SpringMvc

Tags: spring-mvc, url

I have a form through which the user can select the parameters, and I have a `<select>` field of multiple type, and I wonder how many line the user selected in my controller.

my controller is something like that

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/SelectionAppliParametree")
public class SelectionAppliParrametree(@requestParameter("nomAppli") String nomAppli)
{
   /** traitement*/
}
```

but the  champ is multiple and user can choose 1, 2, 3 or more
how can i count the parameters in uri?

Comment: can you provide more specific information on what you seek

Answer (score 0):

If your form is backed by a java object, you can expose that object and model and receive the model object in controller.

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public xxxx controllerMethod(@ModelAttribute("formObject") FormBackingJavaBean formObject) {
  // Business logic to find the usage.
}
```

Comment: my controller is something like that! @Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/SelectionAppliParametree")
public class SelectionAppliParrametree {

Comment: Could you please be specific and give more details?